# Setting Anti-Malware Enabled as default on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services, antimalware

OK, so this is a revised post as I can see some down-votes and the solution, for me, is still not working. As a background, deploying from Visual Studio to a Cloud Service in Azure will reset anti-malware back to original state (disabled). So I am trying to enable this by default.

Steps taken so far:

1. Create Startup folder in the main web project
2. Add to this folder startup.cmd file with the following:

```
    Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\Startup\startup.ps1 >> "c:\logs\startup_ps_log.txt"
```

3. Add to the same folder the powershell script startup.ps1:

```
    
    Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension -ServiceName "myservicename" -AntimalwareConfiguration -Slot "Production"
```

4. Modify the ServiceDefinition.csdef file in the Cloud Service project to call the startup task:

```
    <Startup priority="-2">
        <Task commandLine="startup\startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />      
    </Startup>
```

I deploy my solution and get the same result. Anti-malware is still disabled. If I fire up an RDP session into the VM and interrogate the log I can see it is running but failing to find the specific powershell command/script for AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension:

```
    Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension : The term 
    'Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension' is not recognized as the name of a 
    cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
    name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you're trying to activate AntiMalware from within the cloud service itself. But it should be done from the computer running the deployment and can be done either from Visual Studio for VMs or by ARM PowerShell CmdLets for Cloud Services.

See this [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-antimalware).

Comment: Thanks Roderick but that would not work well with our current deployment mechanism and my understanding is that it can be done this way, we just seem to be missing something.

Comment: In that case, it's like @gvee says, you'll need the module imported.

Answer (score 1):

> The term 'Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The PowerShell session doesn't know what that function is, which means the module containing the code has not been imported.

Add this line before your function call to give it a chance `;-)`

```
Import-Module Azure* -ErrorAction Stop
```

If that fails for any reason then it is likely the module is not available on your target, so **[you'll need to install it!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-5.1.1)**

Comment: Thanks Gvee, tried the first of these and same result. The installing has me confused as the MS docs all state it is installed by default in a disabled state. However I will explore.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Microsoft Antimalware is installed in a disabled state in the Cloud Services platform and requires an action by an Azure application to enable it.

Use the **Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension** Antimalware cmdlet to enable and configure Microsoft Antimalware for your Cloud Service as documented at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azure/Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, it still leaves a lot of questions tho, how to execute PS on cloud service startup, what exactly should be in the XML file. But I guess that is like most MS documentation, technically accurate, but not necessarily the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your Step 3, you write:

```
Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension -ServiceName "myservicename" -AntimalwareConfiguration -Slot "Production"
```

But you don't specify the xml file after `-AntimalwareConfiguration`

Comment: My understanding is it is optional

Comment: I think it's "optional" in the sense that you can add that parameter and it will be looking for a configuration, or you can leave it out.  [Here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Antimalware-For-Azure-5ce70efe/view/Discussions) is an example of the xml file if you need.

Also, stepping back a bit.  Have you installed the [Azure AD module](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2669552/-the-term-cmdlet-name-is-not-recognized-error-when-you-try-to-run-azur)?

Comment: And you added the line:
`Import-Module MSOnline`